# JPopupMenu give initial focus to a child (JTextField), even when exceeding parent frame's boundaries (heavy-weight)

Tags: java, swing, popup, focus

I have this situation where a `JTextField` inside a `JPopupMenu` does not get focus despite calling `requestFocus` when the popup menu exceeds the parent frame's boundaries. This is with different look and feels (e.g. Metal) on Linux/Gtk (not sure it has to do with the platform). Example:

```java
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class FocusTest implements Runnable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new FocusTest());
    }

    public void run() {
        final JFrame f = new JFrame();
        final JButton invoker = new JButton("Pop");
        final JPopupMenu pop = new JPopupMenu();
        final JTextField text = new JTextField(12);
        pop.add(text);
        pop.pack();
        invoker.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                pop.show(invoker, 0, 0);
                System.out.println("here");
                text.requestFocus();
            }
        });
        f.getContentPane().add(invoker);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

With the default frame size, the popup is larger than the frame, and the focus is not given:

[image]

When the window is make larger, opening the popup *gives* initial focus and I can start typing in the text field without mouse interaction:

[image]

This seems to be related to the fact that in the first case the popup is made heavy-weight, and in the second case it is light weight. For example, if I add `pop.setLightWeightPopupEnabled(false);`, then the focus is not given even if the popup is contained inside the parent frame.

How do I ensure that focus is given in any case (also for heavy-weight peers)?

Comment: `JPopupMenu` is a factory based class, that is, it creates its own window, and how it gets done is also dependent on the implementation and (from memory) how the popup is been presented, this some times means that it uses a `JWindow`, which isn't focusable by default.  While there might be a better work around, my solutions usually involve creating an undecorated frame or dialog instead and just doing it myself :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer thank you - `JDialog` worked (not `JWindow` though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So explicitly using an undecorated dialog seems to work:

```java
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class FocusTest implements Runnable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new FocusTest());
    }

    public void run() {
        final JFrame f = new JFrame();
        final JButton invoker = new JButton("Pop");
        final JDialog pop = new JDialog();
        pop.setUndecorated(true);
        final JTextField text = new JTextField(12);
        pop.add(text);
        pop.pack();
        invoker.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                pop.setLocationRelativeTo(invoker);
                pop.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        f.getContentPane().add(invoker);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```